# Visual Studio Git Flow extension create hotfix failing

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional with the GitFlow extension found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-57624.GitFlowforVisualStudio2017). It was working perfectly fine last week, but it has now decided to play up.

When I try to create a hotfix (or feature), it just stops, doesn't create the branch and returns to it's normal window state. I've check the output, and all I get is:

```
Running git flow hotfix start "fix-new-starter"
```

After some investigation, I ran the command `git flow hotfix start "my-fix"` from the Git terminal, and I'm now getting the following error:

```
$ git flow hotfix start
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow: line 115: /gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory
```

I can confirm that the `gitflow-shFlags` file exists on my machine, but it doesn't seem to think it does. Things I've tried:

- Rebooted my machine.
- Reinstalled Git Flow Extension.
- Reinstalled Git for Windows.
- Restarted Visual Studio again.

I cannot seem to get it to work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix my Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of scratching my head, and much playing around with this, I finally got it to work.

From what I could tell, the `GITFLOW_DIR` was not being setup correctly in the `git-flow` script in the `\usr\bin` folder in my Git installation, as when I used `echo` to output it, it came up blank.

What I've now done, is find the directory of my Git installation, and hard code that to the `GITFLOW_DIR` variable in the `git-flow` script.

```
main() {
    # Force the value to be set here.
    export GITFLOW_DIR="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin"

    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        usage
        exit 1
    fi

    .....
```

Now when I run the Git Flow commands, or use the extension, they work fine. Not sure why this has happened, but my fix has made it work again.

Adding `export GITFLOW_DIR="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin"` to line 109 seems to have done the trick.

Note: If your Git installation directory is different, make sure you change the path.

Comment: I had this problem, reinstalling Gitflow with Chocolatey solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on my machine. Can not start new feature because of that error "git-flow: line 115: /gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory".

Comment: I've posted an answer on how to fix it. Let me know if it works for you :)